# How to use Firefox's devtools to inspect web extension content in sidebar?

Tags: html, css, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions, devtools

When web extensions create sidebar content, how does one use Firefox's devtools to inspect that sidebar content while it is presented in the sidebar?

If an example is helpful, please consider the [Tree Style Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/) web extension.

Normally, you can just open Firefox's devtools inspector, and inspect an element.  This does not work for this case.

When it doesn't work, you can then typically set up a remote debugging session for Firefox's devtools.  This works for inspecting the sidebar elements *surrounding* the web extension's content, but does not allow a developer to immediately inspect the content of the web extension itself while it is presented in the sidebar.

The only workaround I have found is to determine the URI of the content in the sidebar, and then open it in its own tab.  Once I've done that, I can inspect it as usual, but I'm looking for a way to inspect the content *while it is displayed in the sidebar*.

Comment: Same as you inspect the hidden scripts, probably: `about:debugging`, [documentation](https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/debugging/) + [tutorial](https://www.reddit.com/r/FirefoxCSS/comments/a6tper/tutorial_inspectingdebugging_an_extension_sidebar/).